# Se puede agrupar los fields en div de un Django form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

que cuando se renderiza un form de django los field se separan en etiquetas p Como se muestra en la etiqueta elements[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

todo ese grupo de etiquetas p necesito dividirlo en 4 grupos de div, para organizarlos en el modal, pudiendo evitar tener que hacerlo 1 por 1 brindando un mejor responsive

mi forms.py donde llamo al modelo central para organizar los field que se mostraran en la vista

```
class CentralForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = central
        fields = [
            'idCentral',
            'nameCentral',
            'indoor',
            'nemonico',
            'fkAtributosCiudades',
            'zona',
            'dirNorm',
            'barrio',
            'comuna',
            'estados',
            'creadoPorI',
            'position'
        ]

        widgets = {
            'position': LeafletWidget(attrs=LEAFLET_WIDGET_ATTRS),
            'dirNorm': DiretionWidget(widgets=any)
        }
```

mi widgets.py aqui tengo alojado la parte del formulario donde esta escrita el campo direccion (funcional)

```
class DiretionWidget(forms.MultiWidget):
   def __init__(self, widgets, attrs=None):
       widgets = (
           forms.Select(choices=DIR_CHOICES),
           forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'numero Ej: 4b, 4'}),
           forms.Select(choices=CAR_CHOICES),
           forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'numero de casa Ej: 4b-54,4-56'}),
           forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Datos adicionales (Opcional)'})
       )
       super(DiretionWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

   def decompress(self, value):
       if value:
           return value
       return [None, None, None, None, None, None]

   def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
       datelist = [
           widget.value_from_datadict(data, files, name + '_%s' % i)
           for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets)]
       try:
           D = str(datelist[0])+' '+str(datelist[1])+' '+str(datelist[2])+' #'+str(datelist[3])+'/'+str(datelist[4])

       except ValueError:
           return ''
       else:
           return str(D)
```

mi views.py

```
class CentralCreate(CreateView):
   model = central
   template_name = 'Central/CentralCreate.html'
   form_class = CentralForm
   success_url = reverse_lazy('listCentral')

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       form = CentralForm()
       form.fields['dirNorm'].label = 'Direccion'
       context['form'] = form
       return context
```

mi CreateCentral.html

```
{% load static %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}
{% leaflet_js plugins="ALL" %}
{% leaflet_css plugins="ALL" %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" ></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='{% static 'dist/leaflet.ajax.min.js'%}'></script>
<style type="text/css">
   .leaflet-container {
       height: 20em;
   }

</style>
{% block form %}
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" id="myModal" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
           <h2 class="modal-title"> Crear Central</h2>
           <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="{% url 'createCentral' %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
               <input type="submit" value="save"/>
            </form>
       </div>

   </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
<script type="text/javascript">
       map = window['leafletmapid_position-map']
       setTimeout(function(){ window['leafletmapid_position-map'].invalidateSize();},400)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

En realidad puedes separar los campos de los formularios utilizando tan solo las plantillas.

Yo utilizo un fichero `form-field.html` como base para cada uno de los campos:

```
<div class='form-field {% if field.errors %}form-field__error{% endif %}'>
{% if field.errors %}
    <div class="form-field__errors">
        {% for item in field.errors %}
        <p class="error">{{ item }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}

    <div class="form-field__controls group-{{ field.widget_type }}">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label}}">{{ field.label|capfirst }}</label>
        {{ field }}
    </div>

{% if field.help_text %}
    <div class='form-field__help'>{{ field.help_text|striptags }}</div>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

En la plantilla de la vista, no tengo más que utilizar este “componente” para cada campo del formulario:

```html
<form>
    {% for field in form %}
    {% include 'form-field.html' %}
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit">enviar</button>
</form>
```

Hay buena documentación (pero en inglés): [Looping over the form’s fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)

La ventaja es que preparas la plantilla una vez y puedes reutilizarla en todos tus proyectos.